# PHP inside echo HTML

Tags: php, theme-development, html

I am a little bit confused about the following code:

i need to add `span class="<?= $styles['core']; ?>"`

```
<?php 
if( ! defined( 'CP_VC_ACTIVE' ) ) {
echo '<li><span class="core">'.esc_html__('Required','cpo').'</span><a target="_blank" href="'. esc_url( admin_url( 'themes.php?page=tgmpa-install-plugins' ) ) . '"> '. esc_html__('hi iam here', 'cpo') . '</a></li>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it the single and double quotes that's confusing you? `<span class="'.$styles['core'].'">` should work or try defining what you want to add as a variable:  `$addthis = $styles['core'];`. Then add the variable like so: `<span class="'.$addthis.'">`.

Comment: it doesn't work , i have fixed it by closing PHP tag and write HTML codes